# In Django ORM, get records whose field value is maximal in a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Consider a simple model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like a single expression which returns a `QuerySet` of all of the `Person` objects whose age is maximal in the table.  I.e. say there are 20 `Person` records, and the largest age is `70` but there are 3 distinct records which have that value.  I would like my queryset to contain exactly those 3 `Person` objects.

I suppose I could do:

```
Person.objects.filter(age=Person.objects.aggregate(models.Max('age'))['age__max'])
```

But wow that seems like a real mess.  And it hits the database twice.  Yuck.

Better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I can't directly answer your question, but I feel like you shouldn't beat up for getting this in one query, making your code clear is also important. So why don't you do:

```
from django.db.models import Max
# assumes that you have at least one record
max_age = Person.objects.aggregate(Max('age'))['age__max']
oldest_folks = Person.objects.filter(age=max_age)
```

`Max` would do `MAX` in sql statement, `filter` would do a simple sql lookup, none of the operations are awfully expensive.